# Change two hr lines under a link to one when hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a website and I've ordered the links as a menu across the top under the main logo, and currently I have two hr tags underneath the menu something like this:

```
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
<hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
<hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
```

And what I'd like to happen is when I hover over a link, for example Link 1, one of the lines disappears from under that one link while still under the other 6 links.

I'm sure there's a way to do this but I'm relatively new to `HTML` and `CSS`.

**Edit**

What I'm asking, is when I select a link, like Link 1, to only have one `<hr>` tag instead of two and keeping two `<hr>` tags on the other links

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that you have 2 `<hr>` under each link in the list ?
If that's the case, here is an example on how to hide one `<hr>` under the hovered link using jQuery.

```js
var $links = $('li > a');
$links.hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('hr:last').css('opacity', 0);
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().find('hr:last').css('opacity', 1);
});
```

```css
hr {
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
li a {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Link 6</a>
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Link 7</a>
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
</li>
```

And here, roughly the same thing without Javascript/jQuery

```css
hr {
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
li a {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
li:hover hr:last-of-type {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Link 6</a>
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Link 7</a>
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
  <hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
</li>
```

Comment: I have all 7 links across horizontally at the top of the page, not down one side, so it would look something like: `Link 1    Link 2    Link 3    etc`

Comment: Ok then, I edited my answer, doest it look more like what you want to do ?

Comment: thanks, but how would I make all the `hr` tags be one straight line?

Comment: Use `float: left` and some `padding` (check the updated snippets)

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is to add a hover event on the anchof like :

```
$( "li a" ).hover(
  function() {
    //When hovering
  }, function() {
    //When loosing hover
  }
);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$( "li a" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( 'hr:eq(0)' ).hide();
  }, function() {
    $( 'hr:eq(0)' ).show();
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
<hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
<hr align="left" width="100%" color="#a2a2a2">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this, using a pseudo element

```css
ul, li, a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  bottom: -12px;
  border-top: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
}
li:hover:after {
  border-top: 0px solid #a2a2a2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="#">Link 7</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't seem to work? It works when I run the code snippet but when I put it in my code, it doesn't?

Comment: @JonSmith This one depends on that the distance is exact measured. If you change `background: white` to `background: red` you'll see it. I will update my answer with a better one in a few minutes.

Comment: It's just not taking the section under the links away

Comment: @JonSmith Added a 2:nd sample, a better one

Comment: I've already set the `ul` tag before in CSS so would calling it again effect it?

Comment: @JonSmith Not as long as you don't change the already given properties. You could of course add the properties I suggest to the existing rule

Comment: I'm in the process of doing this and for some reason the last two links have been put on the next line, so now they aren't all in one line

Comment: @JonSmith If you post a link I'll have a look, but most likely they don't fit on 1 line. I updated my answer adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the `ul` to keep them on 1 line